# How to write an ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets that generates unique alphanumeric outputs based on Google Forms submissions?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-forms

I am attempting to write an ARRAYFORMULA function in Google Sheets that will permit a labelling system for entries submitted through Google Forms.  I want a unique alphanumeric output for each Forms submission entered into the spreadsheet.  Each entry will fall into one of 20 "categories" or headers (determined by the Form responses), each with with its own numbering system.  To illustrate: the first entry designated "HA" would have the output "HA001", the next designated "HA" would have the output "HA002".  But the first entry designated "CP" would similarly have the output "CP001" - regardless of sequence of the  Google Form submissions.

I have made multiple attempts, making use of ROW, COUNTIF, and MATCH functions (all within an ARRAYFORMULA).  As an example:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS( ROW(A:A)=1, "Temp Box ID", LEN(A:A)=0, IFERROR(1/0),LEN(A:A)>1, (D:D&text((row(A:A)+1-match(D:D,D:D,0)),"00000"))))

Here, column D is the "category" (as above, "HA" or "CP").  But the second appearance of a given "category" (in this case, "CA"), returns "CA00003" rather than "CA00002".

[image]

Comment: please share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) with example of your data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following formula-

```
=MAP(D2:INDEX(D2:D,COUNTA(D2:D)),LAMBDA(variable,variable&RIGHT("00000"&COUNTIFS(D2:variable,variable),5)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was able to easily plug this into an arrayformula (with some minor edits) - but this appears to be working great!

Comment: @RMKStevens Glad to know! If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as answered.